# How to get seperate SSD with Windows 10 to appear on Grub in different SSD with Arch

Tags: linux, ssd, grub, arch-linux

I installed Arch this week and have a question regarding Grub.
I have two SSD's in my case, 1 for windows and 1 for Linux. I did my Arch install as UEFI and am now finding out that my Windows 10 is Legacy. Is it at all possible to get my Windows 10 SSD to show up on Grub? (It was working previously with my Antergos install which is now replaced with Arch).
Most of the other threads I can find are specific to dual booting on a single drive.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it's not necessary to go through this process, but if another bootable os is not showing up you'd want to update grub.

As per this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111889/how-do-i-update-grub-in-arch-linux) you want to run this command

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: Thanks, I was forgetting to update grub this whole time :I